# Is there anything in any airport called a "warm apron"?

Tags: airport, terminology

I heard a pilot said they are located at big airports like LAX. But I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: Was your conversation with the pilot in English? If not, could you add the exact words he used in the original language?

Comment: Possible solutions might be airport "hot-spots" (areas of increased risk due to confusing layout), and warm-up or run-up areas on the ramp.

Comment: @Pondlife the conversation was in spanish but what JonathanWalters added is correct, I was refering to the warm-up areas near the runway, but I've never heard of that area before.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *warm up apron* is a portion of the airfield close to the runway entry, where the engine can be warmed up before taking off. It seems to be more frequently used in military documentation.

There are such aprons at Cairns Army Airfield:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1701/00577AD.PDF)</sup>

Found in FAA regulations, e.g. [AC 150/5340-30](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5340_30g.pdf):

> PAPI LHAs must not be located closer than 50 ft from a crossing
>   runway, taxiway, or warm-up apron or within the ILS critical area.

But also in other not regulatory documents, here for synonymous of *hardstand*:

> ... construction of the RMP test section and warm-up apron (hardstand)
>   at the east end of Runway 04-22. The RMP warm-up apron was
>   successfully constructed and has been opened for traffic since October
>   1992.

<sup>Source: [Design, Construction and Performance of Resin Modified Pavement at Fort Campbell Army Airfield, Kentucky](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235016102_Design_Construction_and_Performance_of_Resin_Modified_Pavement_at_Fort_Campbell_Army_Airfield_Kentucky)</sup>

A vintage post-card:

[image]
<sup>Source: [eBay](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/162238461691?rmvSB=true)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

These are sometimes called run-up aprons and its an area where a pilot can perform final preflight checks before taking off as well as engine run-ups and tests where a pilot can do these without worrying about jet blast or propwash kicking up FOD all over a parking apron.  At military bases, this is used as a final once over by ground crews as well as ordies removing the safeties of all external ordnance thus arming the weapons prior to takeoff.